# Окрас предметов

Tags: семантика

Могут ли предметы иметь окрас, или это "удел" живых существ (окрас деревьев, плодов, шиншилл и т. п.)? Например: роговой окрас очков, коричневый окрас очков. Если в этом случае понятие "окрас" неупотребительно, можно ли замест него использовать понятие "окраска" и считать его более общим?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе всего 197 примеров. Удалось найти только 2 с предметами. Какой можно сделать вывод?

Comment: А окраска? Как она сочетается с предсетами?

Comment: У окраски ситуация лучше. Имеется даже несколько примеров в словарях. Но думаю, большинству людей о таком употреблении не известно. Но это точно индивидуально: далеко не о каждом предмете так можно сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Значения практически синонимичны.

ОКРА́С -а; м. Спец. Цвет, окраска (шерсти животного, оперения птиц и т.п.).

ОКРА́СКА, -и, ж.

1. Действие по глаг. окрасить-окрашивать (в 1 знач.). Окраска зданий. Окраска волос.
2. Цвет, оттенок цвета чего-л. Пойманный заяц был маленький, серо-бурого цвета. Такую окраску он сохраняет все время и летом и зимой. Арсеньев, По Уссурийской тайге. Зелень молодняка так приятно выделяется своей светлой и нежной окраской среди листвы старых деревьев. Авдеев, У нас во дворе.
3. перен. Особый смысл, характер, приобретаемый чем-л. под влиянием чего-л., особый оттенок, сообщаемый чему-л. кем-л, чем-л. [Фантастическая легенда] придавала борьбе особую окраску. Короленко, Легенда о царе и декабристе. Мечты о путешествиях приобрели новую окраску, наполнились новым содержанием. Ушаков, По нехоженой земле.

> Иноземная колонизация имела пестрый этнический окрас и иное сословное
> представительство. [Петр Скоробогатый. Русские истоки Новороссии //
> «Эксперт», 2014] Окрас у знамени, конечно, голубой, с оттенками.
> [Андрей Пермяков. Десятая часть года. Почти документальная повесть //
> «Волга», 2010]
>
> Наверху расположены цветные провода, окрас которых соответствует цвету
> кнопок в номерах. [коллективный. Форум: Отель «У погибшего альпиниста»
> (2008-2010)]
>
> Встречались с новоиспеченным владельцем целлюлозно-бумажного комбината
> ― провинциальным нуворишем из меняющих окрас обкомовцев, который
> готовился перебираться в столицу … [Георгий Елин. …и помнúлась им
> Свобода (2008)]
>
> Чистая свинцовая глазурь усиливает темно-желтый цвет до оттенка
> медовой дыни, а соединение меди со свинцом дает зеленый окрас. [Н.
> Малыхина. Наполеон Бонапарт и его окружение. история одного экспоната
> // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]
>
> Нам в этом, как известно, помогают вкусовые ощущения, имеющие
> положительный или отрицательный эмоциональный окрас. [С. Мурик. О
> природе эмоций, или что чувствует амеба в горячей воде // «Наука и
> жизнь», 2006]

Примеры ваши (*роговой окрас очков, коричневый окрас очков*), сдаётся, придуманы по ходу письма. Очки, при частичной их корпусности, не являются по цветности и фактуре цельным предметом, поэтому необходимо ввести ещё одно слово: «*окрас роговой оправы очков*».

Comment: Во всех примерах, что вы привели, нет ни одного, в котором бы шла речь о цвете, оттенке какого-л. неживого предмета

Comment: Наверху расположенные цветные провода... ожили?

Comment: Там просто нужно было избежать тавтологии (повтора слова "цвет").

Comment: Избежать удалось? Да. Благодаря какому слову? Обсуждаемому. Оно уместно? Вполне.

Comment: А повтор звучал бы в разы хуже. Пришлось выбрать меньшее зло)

Comment: Окрас у знамени, конечно, голубой, с оттенками, тоже не в тему?

Comment: Там было больше в тему, чем здесь. Может, с какими-то словами и будет звучать нормально, но не со "знаменем".

Comment: Простите, не заметил.